# cuda visual profiler error with new session

Tags: c++, algorithm, cuda, nvidia

I would you to ask for help. I have some erros when I create new session on Visual Profiler(release 7.0).

I get message error:

> unable to read session timeline.

Then some log message from console :

> ==7804== NVPROF is profiling process 7804, command: C:\Users\Łukasz\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Win32Project1\x64\Release\ConsoleApplication1.exe
>   ==7804== Error: Cannot create profiling file: C:\Users\Łukasz\nvvp_workspace.metadata.plugins\com.nvidia.viper\launch\8\api.log

What is wrong ?

Comment: I don't think visual studio 2015 is an [officially supported environment for CUDA 7](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-microsoft-windows/index.html#system-requirements).

Comment: I change to Visual 2013 and still the same.

Comment: Which version of windows?

Comment: It's windows 8.1 x64

Answer (score 1):

You need to open nvvp.ini (C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v7.5\libnvvp) and change path after `-data` to `c:\yourpath`